Terminal Showing a Prisma Error In PERN App
Error
Argument `user` is missing.
set(): PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `this.prisma[this.sessionModelName].create()` invocation in
/home/muhammed/Desktop/cloud-nest/cloud-nest/node_modules/@quixo3/prisma-session-store/dist/lib/prisma-session-store.js:543:85

  540 case 4:
  541     _a.sent();
  542     return [3 /*break*/, 7];
→ 543 case 5: return [4 /*yield*/, this.prisma[this.sessionModelName].create({
        data: {
          sid: "EzdQTmsgzLmc3zAuzzduHr_ZXQ5hoZn1",
          expiresAt: new Date("2024-10-16T17:32:46.922Z"),
          data: "{\"cookie\":{\"originalMaxAge\":1209600000,\"expires\":\"2024-10-16T17:32:46.922Z\",\"httpOnly\":true,\"path\":\"/\"},\"passport\":{\"user\":1}}",
          id: "EzdQTmsgzLmc3zAuzzduHr_ZXQ5hoZn1",
      +   user: {
      +     create: UserCreateWithoutSessionInput | UserUncheckedCreateWithoutSessionInput,
      +     connectOrCreate: UserCreateOrConnectWithoutSessionInput,
      +     connect: UserWhereUniqueInput
      +   }
        }
      })

Prisma Schema
model User {
  id                Int           @id @default(autoincrement())
  email             String        @unique
  firstName         String?
  lastName          String?
  password          String
  files             File[]        @relation("OwnedFiles")
  folders           Folder[]      @relation("OwnedFolders")
  sharedFiles       SharedFile[]  @relation("UserSharedFiles")
  sharedFolders     SharedFolder[] @relation("UserSharedFolders")
  session           Session[]
}

model Session {
  id              String   @id
  sid             String   @unique
  data            String
  user            User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
  userId          Int
  expiresAt       DateTime
}

I use passportjs to verify the user, following is the session initiation
app.use(
  session({
    store: new PrismaSessionStore(prisma as any, {
      checkPeriod: 2 * 60 * 1000, // Clean up expired sessions every 2 minutes
      dbRecordIdIsSessionId: true,
      dbRecordIdFunction: undefined,
    }),
    secret: "cat",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000, // 14 days
    },
  })
);

I am doing a full stack app based on PERN stack, I am using passportjs to validate user and I am saving session in the prisma. New user registration works, but it give the mentioned error while I try to login with those credentials.
How can I fix this?
